# Why am I getting this error message when I want to find the lags in my time series?

Tags: r, time-series, var, nas

I want to find the lags in my time series of 9 variables using the function of "VARselect" but when I run the model appears "NAs in y".
Does someone know what the problem is?

```
attach(PAISES_ANUAL)

ARMK.ts= ts(MK, start = 1990, frequency = 1)
ARGDP.ts= ts(`GDP PC`, start = 1990, frequency = 1)
ARDCPS.ts= ts(DCPS, start = 1990, frequency = 1)
ARGDS.ts= ts(GDS, start = 1990, frequency = 1)
ARST.ts= ts(ST, start = 1990, frequency = 1)
ARRI.ts= ts(RI, start = 1990, frequency = 1)
ARIN.ts= ts(IN, start = 1990, frequency = 1)
ARFDI.ts= ts(FDI, start = 1990, frequency = 1)
ARCPS.ts= ts(CPS, start = 1990, frequency = 1)


dset=cbind(ARMK.ts, ARGDP.ts, ARDCPS.ts, ARGDS.ts,ARST.ts, ARRI.ts, ARIN.ts, 
ARFDI.ts, ARCPS.ts)
dset

lagselect<- VARselect(dset, lag.max = 7, type = "const")

*Error in VARselect(dset, lag.max = 7, type = "const") :  
 NAs in y *
```

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one NA value in at least one column.
You can identify in which column there is NA by using...

`table(is.na(ARMK.ts))`